# Definitions of uniform space

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space. The collection $\mathcal{A}=\{U_\lambda(x)\}_{\lambda\in \Lambda, x\in X}$, with $U_\lambda(x)\subseteq X$, is called a uniform structure of $X$ if

1. If $x\in X$ and $\lambda\in \Lambda$, then $x\in U_\lambda(x)$.
2. If $\alpha, \beta\in\Lambda$, then there is some $\gamma\in \Lambda$ such that whenever $U_\gamma(x)\subseteq U_\alpha(x)\bigcap U_\beta(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

3)For every $\epsilon\in \Lambda$ there is $\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that whenever $x,y, z\in X$ with $x,y \in U_\lambda(z)$ there follows $x\in U_\epsilon(y)$

Also Let $(X, \mathcal{V})$ be as uniform space $\mathcal{V}=\{V_\alpha\}$ with entourage $\Delta_X\subseteq V_\alpha$.

What is difference between $(X, \mathcal{V})$ and $(X, \mathcal{A})$ in above?

Let uniform space $(X, \mathcal{V})$ with $\mathcal{V}=\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ be given. Define $U_\alpha(x)= V_\alpha[x]=\{y: (x, y)\in V_\alpha\}$. I think that $\mathcal{A}= \{U_\alpha(x)\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda, x\in X}$ is satisfies items 1, 2, 3 in above.
What can say about reverse inclusion?
Is it true that if  $\mathcal{A}=\{U_\lambda(x)\}_{\lambda\in \Lambda, x\in X}$ satisfies in items 1, 2, 3 and take $U_\alpha=\bigcup_{x\in X}U_\alpha(x)\times U_\alpha(x)$, then $\mathcal{U}=\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ is an an uniformity for $X$?

Would you please help me to know it or introduce a reference to study difference between them.

Comment: There aren't many texts that cover this stuff, uniform spaces are out of fashion. Covers and entourages are the most common definition form. Yes the correspondence you gave is standard. The proofs are routine.

Comment: You get a "base" for the entourage uniformity. Also a base for the cover uniformity.

Comment: There’s a short but decent introduction in Chapter 9 of Willard’s *General Topology*.

Comment: Also look at Ryszard Engelking's "General Topology".

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I incidentally found http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/engel/engel.pdf which seems to contain everything from Engelking's book except proofs and exercises. Very useful!

Comment: @PaulFrost I'd rather look at my (very worn) copy close to my computer.. Also missing : the historical discussions, and the examples (for which I also use it quite a lot).

Comment: Would you also need a symmetry condition $x \in U_\epsilon(y) \rightarrow y \in U_\epsilon(x)$?  Otherwise, I think you'd get a quasiuniform space (in the terminology of the Wikipedia article).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a "uniformity" $(X,\mathcal{A})$ as described, gives rise to a
base for a [uniformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) $(X,\mathcal{U})$ in "entourage style" (see the Wikipedia page). Just let $\mathcal{B}(A) = \bigcup\{U_\lambda(x) \times U_\lambda(x): x \in X\}$ where $A = A_\lambda= \{U_\lambda(x): x \in X\}$ is in $\mathcal{A}$ (so $\lambda \in \Lambda$), and check that this forms a base for an entourage uniformity.

And this $\mathcal{A}$ is itself a base for a uniformity in "cover style" : just take the collection of all covers (any kind) that are refined by a member of $\mathcal{A}$. And conversely too if $\mathcal{U}$ is a (base for an) entourage uniformity then  all covers $\{U[x]\mid x \in X\}$, where $U$ ranges over $\mathcal{U}$, form a uniformity as described in your first paragraph.